# Django Unit Testing - Multiple Readonly Databases - Only creating Django models?

Tags: python, django, database, unit-testing

I have a Django API that is accessing 6 different servers/databases. Four of these are read only, and I do not have permissions to create databases/tables.

I want to implement unit testing, so I have set up a secondary `test_settings.py` file that is called if the environment is in test mode. The Django configuration is stored in the "default" database.

When I run test the default test database is created with no issues. When it gets to the second database it creates that as well...but then only puts the `django_migrations` table in with no other models.

Eventually it tries to query a table that it didn't put in and gets a:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "*Table Name*" does not exist
```

What am I overlooking? Everything still works fine in the production databases.

Comment: Hardly enough information. Post the full stacktrace please and give an idea about what your settings file looks like and what your router is like

Comment: As mentioned by e4c5, you might need to provide the `allow_migration` that is specified in your router.